# Additive group $\mathbb{G}_a$ is not isomorphic to multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, algebraic-groups

**Context**
Let $\mathbb{k}$ be an algebrically closed field.
Let us consider the additive group $\mathbb{G}_a \simeq \mathbb{k}$ and the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m \simeq \mathbb{k} \backslash \{0\}$.

I wanted to show that these groups are not isomorphic. Here is my argument:

There is no order $2$ elements in $\mathbb{G}_a$. Indeed, if $x$ was a non-zero element of order $2$ then $2x = 0$ then $x=0$ which is contradictory.
However, in the other side $-1$ is of order $2$ in $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Is my argument right?

I think that there may be a problem with caracteristic 2 fields. So I'm looking for a better argument that does not have any caracteristic issues.

Thanks in advance.

K. Y.

Comment: It depends if you want to show that there is no isomorphism of *abstract group* between the $k$-points of the algebraic groups, or no isomorphism of *algebraic group*. Your argument actually shows there is no abstract group isomorphism if the characteristic is not $2$.

Comment: I think you mean that there is no element of order $2$ in $\mathbb{G}_a$...

Comment: If the characteristic is $2$, consider elements of order $3$.

Comment: @user120527 Actually I meant to prove that there is no isomphism as algebraic group but I thought that it would be enough that there is no isomorphism as abstract group.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You're right. Sorry for the mistake, I'll edit it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct when the characteristic is not $2$.

For an answer that works in any characteristic : show that all elements of $\mathbb{G}_a$ have the same (potentially infinite) order, while $\mathbb{G}_m$ has elements of all finite orders.